# Remove a type of strings from text?

Tags: sed, notepad++

I have similar rows, i want delete the first **...** rows, *not the unique row like* `http://www.filefactory.com/file/a181d18/n/...nimal_2010_.rar`.
I consider **similar rows** until the second arrives on `...` I want delete the second **similar row**. How can I do?

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/152133956/2005_-_Candlemass.part1.rar (not delete)
http://rapidshare.com/files/152133956/2005...emass.part1.rar --> similar (delete)

http://www.filefactory.com/file/a181d18/n/...nimal_2010_.rar -->unique (not delete)

http://www.shragle.com/files/9baa908b/Bvdub-The_First_Day-%2528HN031%2529-2012.rar(not delete)
http://www.shragle.com/files/9baa908b/Bvdu...1%2529-2012.rar --> similar (delete)
```

i 'm using **sed** and **notepad++** on windows

i try use this regex:

```
Find what:         ((?<=\n)|^)([^\n]{40})([^\n]*\n)(.*\n)?\2[^\n]*($|\n)
Replace with:      \2\3\4
```

it works but only if the lines are one below the other, but I would also have a regex that I detect this type of strings in *random* order. Is possible?

Comment: This really sounds like a job for awk and not sed...

Comment: Very difficult to detect those kind of differences in random order using only `sed`. In my opinion not the tools for this kind of job, neither `sed` nor only regular expressions.

Comment: You probably might want to write an if statement in a bash script to find similar ones. This is something that involves logic rather then just regexes.

Comment: unfortunately no idea what to write..can u help me please?

Comment: I don't use Windows, so can't tell the tools provided by that OS to solve this problem. More appropiate tools could be `awk`, `perl`, `python`, `ruby` or similar. All of them much more powerful than `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed ':a;$!N;/^\([^\n]*\)[^\n]*\n\1\.\.\./s/\n.*//;ta;P;D' file
```

Explanation:

- `:a` loop placename holder
- `$!N` append a newline then next line to current line unless last line.
- `/^\([^\n]*\)[^\n]*\n\1\.\.\./` look for near duplicate lines.
- `s/\n.*//` delete previous line.
- `ta` if last substitution was true goto `a`
- `P` print first line in pattern space.
- `D` delete first line in patter space (do not get next line unless empty)

To match random ordered strings, turn to awk.

```
awk '/\.\.\./{o=$0;sub(/\.\.\..*/,"");a[o]=$0;next}{b[$0]}END{for(x in a){for(y in b){if(y ~ a[x]){delete a[x]}}}for(x in a)print x;for(x in b)print x}' file
```

Comment: you say `s/\n.*//` to delete previous line, but if the similar lines are scattered? (Not one after the other). This regex works on Sed for Windows?

Comment: +1. It's a good solution for the example provided, but wouldn't work for strings in random order (the question asks for it).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend getting Cygwin (if you haven't already) and then running `sort -u`. This will sort the input, and then remove any repeated lines. This only works if the order is not important, though.